# RBSheet from react-native-raw-bottom-sheet has a wrong height on first open, and it fixes after reopening it

Tags: react-native, bottom-sheet

When I open the sheet it has a less height than it should have, but if I close the sheet and reopen it, the height will be ok. see the screenshot below.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hpPfw.png)

as you see a part of the confirm bottom is under the screen while it should be like the screenshot 2 below.

[Screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ddZdz.png)

this is where I use the RBSheet component

```
<RBSheet ref={refRBSheet} closeOnDragDown animationType="slide" height={modalHeight} openDuration={400} closeDuration={400}>
        {pReq && (
        <PinRequest
          setrequestpin={(state) => {
            if (state === false) {  
              setPReq(false);
              RBsheetAction('close');
            }
          }}
          selectedChild={pinChild}
          setActiveChild={setactiveChild}
          setModalHeight={setModalHeight}
          firstPick
        />
        )}
      </RBSheet>
```

and here is my PinRequest component

```
import {
  StyleSheet, View, ImageBackground, Platform,
} from 'react-native';
import { Text, Toast } from 'native-base';
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { useTranslation } from 'react-i18next';
import SmoothPinCodeInput from 'react-native-smooth-pincode-input';
import NormalButton from '../buttons/normal';
import styles from '../../pages/home/style';
import { checkFontLat, getFontSize } from '../../utils/fonts';

const pinbg = require('../../assets/pics/auth/pin.png');

const Lato = checkFontLat();

const s = StyleSheet.create({
  center: { justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' },
  text: { color: 'rgba(64, 9, 134, 1)' },
  headingText: {
    marginBottom: 12,
    lineHeight: 30,
    letterSpacing: 0.63,
    fontSize: Platform.select({ ios: 21, android: 18 }),
  },
  cellStyle: {
    borderWidth: 1,
    borderRadius: 24,
    borderColor: '#DADFFF',
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    marginRight: 12,
    width: 56,
    height: 56,
  },
  cellStyleFocused: {
    borderRadius: 24,
    borderColor: '#DADFFF',
  },
});

const ProfileModal = ({
  setrequestpin, selectedChild, setActiveChild, setModalHeight, firstPick = false,
}) => {
  const { t } = useTranslation();
  const [code, setCode] = useState();
  const [height, setHeight] = useState(0);

  const changeHeight = (toValue) => {
    setHeight(toValue);
  };

  const unmount = () => {
    changeHeight(0);
    setrequestpin(false);
  };

  const submitEditting = (pin) => {
    if (selectedChild.pin === pin || selectedChild.pin === code) {
      setActiveChild(selectedChild);
      unmount();
    } else {
      Toast.show({
        text: 'Oops! Incorrect pin.',
        type: 'danger',
        position: firstPick ? 'center' : 'top',
      });
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    changeHeight('auto');
  }, []);

  return (
    <View
      style={[{ alignItems: 'center', height }]}
      onLayout={(e) => setModalHeight(Math.ceil(e.nativeEvent.layout.height + (firstPick ? 0 : 290)))}
    >
      <Text style={[styles.childname, { marginBottom: 17 }]}>{selectedChild.name}</Text>
      <View style={{ alignItems: 'center' }}>
        <Text style={[s.text, s.headingText]}>Enter your pin</Text>
        <Text style={[s.text, { fontFamily: Lato }]}>
          Please enter the pin to access this profile
        </Text>
        <View style={{ marginVertical: 25, marginRight: -12 }}>
          <SmoothPinCodeInput
            autoFocus
            placeholder={(
              <ImageBackground
                resizeMode="contain"
                source={pinbg}
                imageStyle={{ width: '100%' }}
                style={[s.center, { width: 63, height: 63 }]}
              >
                <Text style={{ color: 'rgba(218, 223, 255, 1)' }}>0</Text>
              </ImageBackground>
            )}
            textStyle={{ color: '#400986', fontWeight: 'bold' }}
            cellStyle={s.cellStyle}
            cellStyleFocused={s.cellStyleFocused}
            value={code}
            containerStyle={{ width: '100%' }}
            onTextChange={(pin) => setCode(pin)}
          />
        </View>
      </View>
      <NormalButton
        disabled={code?.length !== 4}
        text={t(firstPick ? 'confirm' : 'switch profile')}
        color="#2DD1CB"
        style={{ marginHorizontal: 30 }}
        textStyle={{ fontSize: getFontSize(18), lineHeight: 27, letterSpacing: 0.54 }}
        onPress={submitEditting}
      />
      {
        !firstPick && (
        <NormalButton
          text="Cancel"
          color="rgba(63, 9, 134, 0.6)"
          bordered
          onPress={unmount}
          style={{ marginBottom: 0, opacity: 0.6, marginHorizontal: 30 }}
          textStyle={{ fontSize: getFontSize(18), lineHeight: 27, letterSpacing: 0.54 }}
        />
        )
      }
    </View>
  );
};

export default ProfileModal;
```

I tried to remove or change the height given to RBSheet component or the onLayout given to the View in PinRequest component.
I tried to change the styles, but nothing worked.